# Greater than or less than the cutoffs calculated using optimal.cutpoints?

Tags: r, regression, binary-data

I'm generating some optimal cutoff values using the R package OptimalCutpoints.

This might be a silly question, but is there a function in this package that will just tell me whether healthy individuals are generally greater than or less than the cutoff calculated using optimal.cutpoints? I can't easily work it out (e.g. mean(healthy) > mean(unhealthy)) and I just wondered if I'd missed something obvious.

Obviously I can tell by looking at plots, but ideally I'd rather automate the process.